# Upgrade PHP XSLT processor to XSLT 2.0

Tags: php, xslt, xslt-2.0, libxslt

Is it possible/easy to upgrade PHP's library to use XSLT 2.0?

Current set up:

```
xsl
XSL     enabled
libxslt Version     1.1.24
libxslt compiled against libxml Version     2.6.32
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.24
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @Louis W: I think there is no "native" PHP XSLT 2.0 processor. But there are XSLT 2.0 processor for many platform, and I think there is a way for PHP script to connect with other server process.

Comment: XSLT is provided by libxslt for the libxml2 library, which currently _only_ supports XSLT 1.0 / XPATH 1.0. Can't find a roadmap atm. whether they are even trying to implement XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Wrikken - Guess it's not possible. Thanks for the help thou. Mind posting an answer so I can accept it and close this question?

Comment: I'll wait just a little while to see it it may be a feature request on http://bugzilla.gnome.org/. which I cannot reach a.t.m. (can anybody else reach that site / check?)

Comment: @Wrikken: You are right about "native" PHP XSLT library, but if server platform is java as suggested, then @Louis W could run a java XSLT 2.0 processor (like Saxon) with a PHP/Java bridge. Don't lock yourself to XSLT 1.0. Update!

Comment: @Alejandro: indeed, that could work. It has nothing to do with an 'upgrade' of PHP, but if one _needs_ 2.0 I'd certainly go a route like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Saxon-C](http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/) project provides a PHP API for its XSLT 2.0 implementation.

Here is the basic installation process:

> Please have the following packages on your machine to build the Saxon/C PHP extension: make, php-devel, (php5-dev/php55-dev/php55w-devel), apache2 or httpd, gcc-c++ or g++, gcj (or just link the jni.h file)
>
> Run the commands:

```
phpize
./configure --enable-saxon
make
sudo make install
```

> Update the php.ini file (if using Ubuntu it is usually in the location '/etc/php5/apache2/') to contain the php extension. Insert the following in the Dynamic Extensions section: extension=saxon.so
>
> Run the command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Example code:

```
<?php 
/* simple example to show transforming to string */
 function exampleSimple1($proc, $xmlfile, $xslFile){
    $proc->setSourceFile($xmlfile);
    $proc->setStylesheetFile($xslFile);

    $result = $proc->transformToString();               
if($result != null) {               
echo '<b/>exampleSimple1:</b/><br/>';       
echo 'Output:'.$result;
} else {
    echo "Result is null";
}
$proc->clearParameters();
$proc->clearProperties();            
}


$foo_xml = "xml/foo.xml";
$foo_xsl = "xsl/foo.xsl";

$proc = new SaxonProcessor();

//On Windows we recommend setting the cwd using the overloaded constructor 
//because there remains an issue with building Saxon/C with PHP when using the function VCWD_GETCWD. i.e. $proc = new SaxonProcessor('C://www/html//trax//');

$version = $proc->version();
echo 'Saxon Processor version: '.$version;
echo '<br/>';        
exampleSimple1($proc, $foo_xml, $foo_xsl);
?>
```

The libxslt2 and libexslt libraries, which are limited to XSLT 1.0, XPath 1.0, and EXSLT support, are used to provide the default XSLT processor for PHP. The [XML_XSLT2Processor](http://xslt2processor.sourceforge.net) project is intended to provide an upgrade path.

Here is the basic installation process:

> Follow the instructions provided on the site of the processor you want to use for instructions on how to install that XSLT processor. Basically, you'll be required to extract the processor binary in some directory.
>
> Once you have the processor set up, you can download XML_XSLT2Processor.
>   Using the PEAR installer
>
> If you don't already have the PEAR installer, check the installation instructions on the PEAR site (basically, on Windows, you start the go-pear.bat file in PHP's folder, and in the typical case click "Enter" all the way), and install the PEAR installer a.k.a. the "PEAR package manager".
>
> Once you have the PEAR installer, you can install XML_XSLT2Processor from it, by simply typing
>   pear install path/to/the/tgz/arhive
>   but replace the path of course. For example, if version 0.5.3 was in the same folder as the PHP folder, you can install it with the command
>   pear install XML_XSLT2Processor_v0_5_3.tgz

Manual installation

> If you don't have (access to) the PEAR installer, you can still install XML_XSLT2Processor by extracting the contents of the archive in any directory. However, it is recommended that this directory is among the paths in your include_path, which you can specify in php.ini. To more closely emulate the PEAR installer, you may also rename the "XSLT2Processor-verion" directory to "XML".

Usage

> Once all of the above is done, you can create a new PHP file and include XML_XSLT2Processor in it. If you've used the PEAR installer, "XSLT2Processor.php" should be available from the "XML" folder, thus:

```
<?php 
include "XML/XSLT2Processor.php";
//The rest of the code
?>
```

> You'll need the include line in the PHP file that will be using the class and it should occur before you use any of the functions in that class. The rest of the documentation will show you how to construct the XML_XSLT2Processor class, as well as explain each function's prototype and give some examples.
>
> Note that if you've worked with the PHP XSL extension before using this one, the only thing you really must know is the XML_XSLT2Processor::__construct() function. The rest is compatible with it, though there are some new features available only here. Be aware that the registerPHPFunctions() and setProfiling() functions are not available due to the architecture of the class (not being a PECL extension and all...).

**References**

- [Installing an XSLT Processor](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html)
- [XSLT2Processor Project News](http://sourceforge.net/p/xslt2processor/news/)
- [Saxon-C Product Information](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml)
- [Saxon-C PHP API](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/php_api.xml)