# How do I update the version of xpath in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will XPath 2.0 and/or XSLT 2.0 be implemented in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085632/will-xpath-2-0-and-or-xslt-2-0-be-implemented-in-php)

I think I'm using xpath 1.0 because I don't have the `lower-case()` function. My PHP version is **5.3.8**. How do I update xpath to the 2.0 version?

Comment: Alternative: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php

Comment: You might have some more luck cross-posting to serverfault.

Comment: Use a magic wand -- there is nothing like "upgrade" and AFAIK PHP is only integrated with an XPath 1.0 engine. If there is a way to use from PHP an external, 3rd party product, you may choose to use any existing XSLT 2.0 or XQuery  processor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately no-one has upgraded the PHP XPath library to version 2.0. If you have lots of spare time or money, you would to do the community a great service by undertaking this work. If you haven't got lots of spare time or money, then hopefully you will understand why no-one else has taken it on. Sadly, this is the downside to free software; there's often no investment going into it.

**UPDATE 2022-11-25**

SaxonC now provides XPath 3.1 functionality with C, C++, PHP, and Python APIs. Disclaimer: this is my company's product.