# how can I make xpath match whitespace?

Tags: xpath, whitespace

I can match `sometext` and `othertext` in

```
<br>
sometext
<br>
othertext
```

using xpath selector '//br/following-sibling::text()'

but if there is only whitespace after the `<br>` element

```
<br>

<br>
othertext
```

only the second match occurs. Is it possible to match whitespace as well?

I tried

```
//br/following-sibling::matches(., "\s+")
```

to attempt to match whitespace without success.

Answer (score 0):

'matches' is to match  regular-expressions, not to match nodes. And it can't be used with an axis specifier. You could use it as condition like:

```
//br/following-sibling::text()[matches(., "\s+")]
```

Or without regexs (might be faster depending on the implementation), checking if it is all whitespace and not the empty string:

```
//br/following-sibling::text()[(normalize-space(.) = "") and (. != "")]
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to work. I tried using `//br/following-sibling::text()[matches(., "\s+")]` on `<br>

sdfs

<br>

<p>sdfd</p>` without result. I noticed that if I tried `//br/following-sibling::text()[matches(., "\s+")] | //br/following-sibling::text()` this also fails to produce a match, even though `//br/following-sibling::text()` does find a match on `sdfd`, suggesting there is perhaps some syntax problem with my use of matches(). `//br/following-sibling::text()[(normalize-space(.) eq "") and (. ne "")]` likewise gave no match.

Comment: in which program are you using it? matches only exists in XPath 2. And your example is not valid xml, so it need some kind of html parser

Comment: I'm using the PHP 5.3.8 version of Xpath. It seems to work without valid XML, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023160/how-do-i-update-the-version-of-xpath-in-php) suggests that I'm using 1.0, and there is no way to fix this. Is there an XPath 1 way to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you want to find text nodes that are only whitespace or that contain whitespace? the normalize-space version should work for former case in XPath 1

Comment: I want to find text nodes containing only whitespace. However, `//br/following-sibling::text()[(normalize-space(.) eq "") and (. ne "")]` does not identify such a node. If I use `//br/following-sibling::text()` I get the expected results for non-whitespace-only nodes, but if I use the prior version to identify whitespace-only nodes, I get no result. I am testing with the text `<br>

sdfs

<br>

<p>sdfd</p>`

Comment: Perhaps you have to use = instead of eq, and != instead of ne in XPath 1

Comment: I tried `//br/following-sibling::text()[(normalize-space(.) = "") and (. != "")]` and `//br/following-sibling::text()[(normalize-space(.) == "") and (. !== "")]` but these also produce no result.

Comment: well, the version with a single = works for me (e.g. in http://www.xpathtester.com/test, after changing the html in valid xml). Perhaps your html parser trims the text nodes.