# Using RegEx + XPath to check 2 keywords

Tags: php, regex, xpath

$string() = "This is with admin charges";

What I intend to do is to write down an X-Path with RegEx to return the statement above true in the sense that when $string contains "admin charge", then the statement returns true.

See, the statement above can have the following keywords,

> 1. admin && charge || charges
> 2. administrative && charge || charges
> 3. administration && charge || charges

See, all and all, the root keyword here is "admin" and "charge".

Therefore, I would like to write a script that incorporates X-Path and RegEx in it.

The following is my approach so far,

```
contains(upper-case(normalize-space($string)), "ADMIN CHARGES")
```

This is still only matches exactly.

I researched, but mostly is to check for single keyword, like

```
contains(upper-case($string), "^[m/ADMIN CHARGE/]"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this PHP? you can add another tag on your question for that if so.

Comment: so why not use `contains($string, 'admin') | contains($string, 'charge')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression functions are part of the [XPATH 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax) syntax.

However, PHP uses the [libxml PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php) to handle its XML Manipulation, which implements the [XPATH 1.0 spec only](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085666/165969) shows an alternative using the PHP/Java Bridge and Saxon. It's probably the best option for the moment.

Using a XSLT 2.0 library, one could use the [matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function. From TFM:

```
fn:matches($input as xs:string?, $pattern as xs:string) as xs:boolean
fn:matches( $input   as xs:string?,
            $pattern     as xs:string,
            $flags   as xs:string) as xs:boolean



matches(., "admin\S*\scharges?", "i")
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning @JWiley's comment into an answer:

```
contains($string,'admin') and contains($string,'charge')
```

Comment: At the moment it's applied as what JWiley suggested and @Phrogz answered. But I was hoping if the answer given, can be applied where XPath and RegEx be used. Even better, if RegEx be used in this case.